# is there an "if in" operator in PHP?

Tags: php, python

i was looking to something that checks whether a string exists inside another, as in python:

```
print "a" in "aloha"
```

wold return 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strpos("aloha", "a") !== false
```

Returns true is the letter a is in the word aloha.

**Note:** Its important to use `!==` and not `!=` as in PHP `0 == false`.

Answer (score 3):

[strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$pos = strpos("aloha", "a");
```

**EDIT**

You can verify the existence of string by putting `IF` like this:-

```
if (strpos("aloha", "a") !== false) {
     echo "The string was found";

} else {
     echo "The string was not found";
}
```

Comment: this checks if it exists inside aloha? i need the existence verified, not the location

Comment: @tekknolagi you have to check for false with the type checker as well (with `===` or `!==`) otherwise if the first character in the string contains what you are searching for, you will get `false` but not `=== false`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$mystring = 'aloha';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
echo $pos // return 0 

if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [**`srtpos()`**](https://www.php.net/strpos) function to check if the position of a string inside another is not false -- i.e. if the string contains the other :

```
if (strpos("aloha", "a") !== false) {
    // a is contained in aloha
}
```

The first parameter being the *haystack* -- the string that could contain what you are searching ; and the second parameter being the *needle* -- the string you are searching.

As noted in the manual *(quoting)* :

> This function may return Boolean
> `FALSE`, but may also return a
> non-Boolean value which evaluates to
> `FALSE`, such as `0` or `""`.
>
> Please read the section on
> [Booleans](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more information.
>
> Use [the `===` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for
> testing the return value of this
> function.

If you want the search to be case-insentive, you'll use the [**`stripos()`**][4] function, btw.